# jQuery $.ajax post datas & fileDownload escaping

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to send some html datas to a PHP script with jQuery. with ajax, i do this:

```
var donnees = $('body').html();
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "content=" + donnees,
    success: function (retour) {
        console.log(retour);
    }
});
```

In php, i receive the datas like this:

```
<div class=\"titre\"></div><div class=\"texte\"></div>
```

And it work pretty good..

When i try to use $.fileDownload (a jquery plugin)

```
var donnees=$('body').html();
$.fileDownload($(this).prop('action'), {
                preparingMessageHtml: "wait during generation.",
                failMessageHtml: "error",
                httpMethod: "POST",
                data: "datas="+donnees
            });
```

I do exactly the same thing but in php i only receive this:

```
<div class
```

I think that jQuery escape the string but i don't know how.

**Edit:**

Even if I add an addslashes() function (i found it on stack) in the console i get the good datas like this:

```
<div class=\"titre\"></div><div class=\"texte\"></div>
```

But no change in PHP...

**EDIT 2:**

The problem is the equal character, it decomposed the post request and i just receive the first part in php. So how can I escape it ?

## EDIT 3:

I finally understand why it's not working... $.fileDownload create an iframe with a form in get, and the function try to put my post data in so the only things that it put in it's:

```
<div class
```

Before the equal.. I've no solution...

Comment: prop this is removing the data try to replace it

Comment: What do you mean ? By what should i replace it ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prop.asp check this..

Comment: "prop this is removing the data try to replace it" from what I've read, it only return the adress of the form... and give it to fileDownload function.....

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

```
var donnees=$('body').html();
$.fileDownload($(this).attr('action'), {
                preparingMessageHtml: "wait during generation.",
                failMessageHtml: "error",
                httpMethod: "POST",
                data: "datas="+donnees
            });
```

Comment: It don't change anything... I think that $.ajax escape the data and file download don't..